# CodeIgniter form_open_multipart, como usar

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou usando o CodeIgniter em um projeto mas estou com uma dificuldade para fazer o envio das informações, tenho uma view que contém um formulário com os campos de cadastro:

```
            <?php

             echo form_open_multipart('Controller_site/cadastro_form');

             ?>

            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="pais" placeholder="País">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dentro dessa view eu tenho vários outros campos que estão sendo "embrulhados" com divs (Bootstrap) para montar o layout.Estou fechando o formulário na última div:

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" align="center">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>

    <?php
     echo form_close();

     ?>

</div>
```

No Controller_site tenho a seguinte função:

```
 public function cadastro_form(){


    $data = 'null';


        $data = array(
            'pais' => $this->input->post('pais'),
            'name_users' => $this->input->post('name_users'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'date_nasc' => $this->input->post('date_nasc'),
            'sexo' => $this->input->post('sexo'),
            'cpf' => $this->input->post('cpf'),
            'mail' => $this->input->post('mail'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'cep' => $this->input->post('cep'),
            'logradouro' => $this->input->post('logradouro'),
            'bairro' => $this->input->post('bairro'),
            'num' => $this->input->post('num'),
            'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
            'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
            'payment' => $this->input->post('payment'),
            'num_cart' => $this->input->post('num_cart'),
            'validade' => $this->input->post('validade'),
            'agencia' => $this->input->post('agencia'),
            'conta' => $this->input->post('conta'),
            'cvv' => $this->input->post('cvv'),
            'login' => $this->input->post('login'),
            'senha' => $this->input->post('senha'),
            'confirmar_senha' => $this->input->post('confirmar_senha'),





        );


        $this->Model_site->cadastro($data);

        redirect("index", 'redirect');


    }
}
```

No model: 
     public function cadastro ($data){

```
    return $this->db->insert('tb_users',$data);
}
}
```

Eu preencho os dados do formulário e nada acontece a página fica do mesmo jeito o botão "parece" nem ter efeito de botão.

Obs: O arquivo do banco de dados já está configurado.

Comment: Botão com `type="button"` não submete formulário. Coloque `type="submit"`

Comment: Deu certo! Muito Obrigada (; Poderia me ajudar em outra coisa, a url está duplicando sabe como posso resolver:  http://localhost/superbat/index.php/Controller_site/localhost/Superbat/Controller_site/cadastro_form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que você colocou

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
```

O elemento `<button>` com `type="button"` não faz a submissão do formulário. Ele é mais utilizado quando irá efetuar uma requisição AJAX ou executar alguma ação na própria página.

Para fazer a submissão do formulário, altere para `type="submit"`:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
```

Comment: +1 Muito Obrigada!